# Why can't I setuid binaries like apt?

Tags: linux, setuid

During all my education I've been taught that the `setuid` would allow anyone that has the execution privilege on a file to run it as the owner. However it seems that I'm not able to setuid a binary and run it as simple user. Here's what I tried :

```
root@pc# chmod u+s,o+x /usr/bin/apt
root@pc# su - zero
zero@pc$ apt update
[sudo] password for zero: 
Sorry, user zero is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt update' as root on pc.
```

It works like a charm by default on `/usr/bin/passwd` but it seems that Linux doesnt allow me to set it on other binaries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually calling `/usr/bin/apt` or do you perhaps have an alias for `apt='sudo apt'`?

Comment: I'm using ```apt update``` not the direct path to the binary

Comment: What happens when you try `/usr/bin/apt update`?

Comment: Well... it works! Stupid from me to not try the direct path, but it's weird that the ```apt``` doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

The message shown indicates that `apt` is 'caught' by `sudo` probably by an alias.

Use the absolute path to `/usr/bin/apt` to avoid that and to make sure you are using the actual binary from you've modified the attributes.

Comment: One might also use `command apt` to avoid an alias or function.